# Constructing a Binary Tree with node sharing same information

Tags: java

I wanted to build a binary tree in java where some nodes must be the same as in another part.

For example, i have my tree in one side and a node in another side (Set class). The node at the other side is a node which will be also at the tree. And that node in the tree may be multiple or single.

So, basically, we have a node sharing informations with the tree.
When i will change the content of that node, it must also change the content in the tree !
So i decided to write something as a proof of concept, and couldn't make it ...

This is my code:
**Main Class**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Set s = new Set();
        System.out.println(s.toString());

        Node n1 = new Node(new String("2"),null,null);
        Node n2 = new Node(new String("3"),null,null);
        Node n3 = new Node(new String("+"),n1,n2);

        s.setIdentifier(n3);
        System.out.println(s.toString());
    }
}
```

**Set Class**

```
public class Set {
    private Node identifier; // This is the node where is apart of the tree
    private Node head; // This is the head of the tree

    // Pre-Condição : Cria o conjunto de universo
    public Set() {
        Node id = new Node(new String("x"), null, null);
        this.identifier = id;
        Node left = new Node(new String("<"), this.identifier, new Node(new String("0"), null, null));
        Node right = new Node(new String(">="), this.identifier, new Node(new String("0"), null, null));
        this.head = new Node(new String("&&"), left, right);
    }

    // Pre-Condicao : Cria o conjunto vazio
    public Set(String identifier) {
        Node id = new Node(identifier);
        this.identifier = id;
        this.head = null;
    }

    // Pre-Condicao: Cria o conjunto dado
    public Set(String identifier, Node h) {
        Node id = new Node(identifier);
        this.identifier = id;
        this.head = h;
    }

    public Node getHead() {
        return head;
    }

    public void setHead(Node head) {
        this.head = head;
    }

    public void setIdentifier(Node identifier) {
        if (this.identifier != null) {
            this.identifier = identifier;
        }
    }

    public Node getIdentifier() {
        return this.identifier;
    }

    public void isntASet() {
        this.identifier = null;
    }

    public String toStringSort(String type) {
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        if (this.identifier != null && this.head != null) {
            s.append(this.identifier.toStringSort(type));
            s.append(" | ");
            s.append(this.head.toStringSort(type));
        }
        return s.toString();
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        if (this.identifier != null && this.head != null) {
            s.append(this.toStringSort("infix"));
        } else if (this.identifier != null && this.head == null) {
            s.append("{");
            s.append(this.identifier.toStringSort("infix"));
            s.append(" | ");
            s.append(" }");
        } else {
            s.append("Problem detected with the expression of the Set (not a boolean Expression).");
        }
        return s.toString();
    }
}
```

**Node Class**

```
public class Node {
    private String data;
    private Node left;
    private Node right;

    public Node(String data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
    }

    public Node(String data, Node left, Node right) {
        this.data = data;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }

    public Node(Node n) {
        this.data = n.getData();
        this.left = n.getLeft();
        this.right = n.getRight();
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Node getLeft() {
        return left;
    }

    public void setLeft(Node left) {
        this.left = left;
    }

    public Node getRight() {
        return right;
    }

    public boolean doesLeft() {
        return (this.left != null) ? true : false;
    }

    public boolean doesRight() {
        return (this.right != null) ? true : false;
    }

    public void setRight(Node right) {
        this.right = right;
    }

    public Node clone() {
        return new Node(this);
    }

    public String toStringSort(String type) {
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

        if (type.equals("prefix")) {
            s.append(this.data.toString());
            if (this.left != null) {
                s.append(this.left.toStringSort("prefix"));
            }
            if (this.right != null) {
                s.append(this.right.toStringSort("prefix"));
            }
        } else if (type.equals("infix")) {
            if (this.left != null) {
                s.append("(" + this.left.toStringSort("infix"));
            }
            s.append(this.data.toString() + " ");
            if (this.right != null) {
                s.append(this.right.toStringSort("infix") + ")");
            }
        } else if (type.equals("postfix")) {
            if (this.left != null) {
                s.append(this.left.toStringSort("postfix"));
            }
            if (this.right != null) {
                s.append(this.right.toStringSort("postfix"));
            }
            s.append(this.data.toString());
        }
        return s.toString();
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

        s.append(this.data.toString());

        return s.toString();
    }
}
```

And the result of my output from my main class is that one :

```
x  | ((x < 0 )&& (x >= 0 ))
(2 + 3 ) | ((x < 0 )&& (x >= 0 ))
```

Normally, every 'x' where appears in my function should be replaced by the '2+3'. Which is not being replaced as shown in the figure...
What's wrong whit my code ? Should i use another architecture ?
Thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why do you use ``String.<init>(String)`` to copy the literals? And you use ``Node.<init>(String, Node, Node)`` where you could simply take ``Node.<init>(String)``...

Comment: Where are you saying that ? which class ?

Comment: It's present overall in the ``Main`` and ``Set`` class, not to note that there are more weired cases with ``StringBuilder``

Comment: Explain yourself please ...
If i'm doing wrong with StringBuilder tell me what is wrong ... 
Regarding to the `new String("x")`, there is no problem with that ... I could omit sure ... But it's not a problem :)

Answer (score 0):

When you set the identifier, you forgot to set the head too. The identifier is printed out correctly, and so is the head in the toStringSort funtion:

```
public String toStringSort(String type){
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    if(this.identifier != null && this.head != null) {
        s.append(this.identifier.toStringSort(type));
        s.append(" | ");
        s.append(this.head.toStringSort(type));
   }
   return s.toString();
}
```

The head is initialized with the left and right being a reference to the nodes:

```
    Node left = new Node(new String("<"),this.identifier, new Node(new String("0"),null,null));
    Node right = new Node(new String(">="),this.identifier, new Node(new String("0"),null,null));
    this.head = new Node(new String("&&"), left,right);
```

This is what is printed out in the toStringSort, as these references are never touched.

One more thing about your implementation. I think you're making this too complicated. Why don't you build the tree just out of nodes? You could build a tree easily in the way that every node contains references to it's father and it's children. 
Now when you change a node, every occurence of this node is changed, and as it's only a refence, the node is changed in every of it's occurencs.

Comment: I didn't understand... can you make me an example ?